# Vertx Event bus bridge with 'io.vertx~mod-web-server~2.0.0', not getting the data

Tags: java, vert.x

I was just trying to create a html page to get a string and display it again in the same page.
My index.html ,

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>

</head>
<body>
    <ul class="my-maps">
    </ul>
    <h2>Create a Map</h2>
    <form class="create-form">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
        <input type="submit" value="Create">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sockjs-0.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vertxbus-2.1.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/client.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I point my browser to localhost:8080, I get these errors

```
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:8080/eventbus/069/yp3vm_fs/websocket. that.ws = new Constructor(that.url);

The connection to ws://localhost:8080/eventbus/069/yp3vm_fs/websocket was interrupted while the page was loading. that.ws = new Constructor(that.url);
```

Both these errors occur in sockjs-0.3.js.

My client.js:

```
var eb = null;
  function openConn() {
    if (!eb) {
      eb = new vertx.EventBus("http://localhost:8080/eventbus");
    }
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
      openConn();
      $('.create-form').submit(function() {
          var value = $("#name").val();
          console.log('name = '+value);
      });
  });
```

My java verticle ,

```
public class Mymap extends Verticle{

    public void start() {
        final Logger logger = container.logger();
        logger.info("Starting mymap");
        JsonObject config = new JsonObject();
        config.putNumber("port", 8080);
        config.putString("host", "localhost");
        config.putBoolean("bridge", true);

        JsonArray inboundPermitted = new JsonArray();
        JsonObject addrss1 = new JsonObject().putString("address", "saveMyMap");
        inboundPermitted.add(addrss1);      
        JsonObject addrss2 = new JsonObject().putString("address", "myMaps");
        inboundPermitted.add(addrss2);
        JsonObject addrss3 = new JsonObject().putString("address", "delMyMap");
        inboundPermitted.add(addrss3);

        config.putArray("inbound_permitted", inboundPermitted);

        container.deployModule("io.vertx~mod-web-server~2.0.0-final", config);

        HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();

        server.requestHandler(new Handler<HttpServerRequest>() {
            public void handle(HttpServerRequest request) {
                if (request.path().equals("/")) {
                    request.response().sendFile("./web/index.html");
                }
                if (request.path().endsWith("sockjs-0.3.js")) {
                    request.response().sendFile("./web/js/sockjs-0.3.js");
                }
                if (request.path().endsWith("vertxbus-2.1.js")) {
                    request.response().sendFile("./web/js/vertxbus-2.1.js");
                }
                if (request.path().endsWith("jquery-2.1.0.js")) {
                    request.response().sendFile("./web/js/jquery-2.1.0.js");
                }
                if (request.path().endsWith("client.js")) {
                    request.response().sendFile("./web/js/client.js");
                }
            }
        }).listen(8080, "localhost");
    }
}
```

I am using the gradle template for my example, and running it using "gradlew.bat runMod".

Answer (score 1):

You asked your question also over at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vertx/ONoF_zN0kAc where you got help and insights formulating a different approach.

Regarding your posted issue here: As you boot up `mod-web-server` AND your own HTTPServer on the same port `8080` they are actually disturbing each other.

The minimal change of your self-started HTTPServer to

```
}).listen(8081, "localhost");
```

instead of `8080` would already solve the WebSocket connect issue, as it on the same port shortly connects but then crashed because of the inconsistency.

Best